# Letters, Get Moving! Pt. 2

Tags: code-golf, string, permutations

The first [Letters, Get Moving!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/66556/letters-get-moving) was very popular, but had limited participation. This one will be easier to solve, but hopefully involve some tricks in golfing.

You are given a string of only lowercase letters. For each letter, with position in the alphabet *m*, move it so it becomes the *m*th letter from the end. If the value of *m* is longer than the length of the string, move it to the very front. Output only the fully transformed string.

**Examples:**

**"giraffe"**

- 'g' is the 7th letter in the alphabet, it is already the 7th letter from the back, so leave it.
- 'i' is the 9th letter, since 9 is bigger than the length of the word, it goes to the front, so the string becomes `igraffe`
- 'r' is the 18th letter, like 'i' it goes to the front: `rigaffe`
- 'a' is the 1st letter, it goes to the very end: `rigffea`
- 'f' is the 6th letter, it becomes the 6th from the back: `rfigfea`
- the next 'f' is also the 6th letter, so it also goes to 6th from the back : `rffigea`
- 'e' is the 5th letters, it goes to 5th from the back: `rfefiga`

**"flower"**

- 'f' (6) => `flower`
- 'l' (12) => `lfower`
- 'o' (15) => `olfwer`
- 'w' (23) => `wolfer`
- 'e' (5) => `weolfr`
- 'r' (18) => `rweolf`

**"pineapple"**

- 'p' (16) => `pineapple`
- 'i' (9) => `ipneapple`
- 'n' (14) => `nipeapple`
- 'e' (5) => `nipaepple`
- 'a' (1) => `nipepplea`
- 'p' (16) => `pnipeplea`
- 'p' (16) => `ppnipelea`
- 'l' (12) => `lppnipeea`
- 'e' (5) => `lppneipea` (make sure you move the *e* that hasn't been moved already! Here it doesn't matter, but below it does.)

*Thanks to @Neil for improving the test cases with these 3 additions:*

**"pizza"**

- 'p' (16) => `pizza`
- 'i' (9) => `ipzza`
- 'z' (26) => `zipza`
- 'z' (26) => `zzipa` (moving the second z!)
- 'a' (1) => `zzipa`

**"abracadabra"**

- 'a' (1) => `bracadabraa`
- 'b' (2) => `racadabraba`
- 'r' (18) => `racadabraba`
- 'a' (1) => `rcadabrabaa`
- 'c' (3) => `radabrabcaa`
- 'a' (1) => `rdabrabcaaa`
- 'd' (4) => `rabrabcdaaa`
- 'a' (1) => `rbrabcdaaaa`
- 'b' (2) => `rrabcdaaaba`
- 'r' (18) => `rrabcdaaaba`
- 'a' (1) => `rrbcdaaabaa`

**"characters"**

- 'c' (3) => `haractecrs`
- 'h' (8) => `arhactecrs`
- 'a' (1) => `rhactecrsa`
- 'r' (18) => `rhactecrsa`
- 'a' (1) => `rhctecrsaa`
- 'c' (3) => `rhtecrscaa`
- 't' (20) => `trhecrscaa`
- 'e' (5) => `trhcrescaa`
- 'r' (18) => `rtrhcescaa`
- 's' (19) => `srtrhcecaa`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### CJam, <s>41</s> 38 bytes

```
lee_S+W%\{Xa-X1='`-/(Xa+\L*+}fX1>W%1f=
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=lee_S%2BW%25%5C%7BXa-X1%3D'%60-%2F(Xa%2B%5CL*%2B%7DfX1%3EW%251f%3D&input=pineapple)

Comment: Upvoting as it's the only other answer that works on all of my test cases.

Comment: Shortest to pass all test cases!

Answer (score 5):

## Python 3, 78 bytes.

Saved 2 bytes thanks to orlp.
Saved 7 bytes thanks to DSM.

```
x=input()
y=[]
for z in x:m=max(len(x)-ord(z)+96,0);y[m:m]=z
print(''.join(y))
```

Builds the word as a list then joins it.

Comment: `(q-p,0)[p>q]` is longer than `min(q-p,0)`.

Comment: It is, but that doesn't do the same thing. That's always going to return 0 or a negative.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `max(q-p,0)`.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, 86 bytes

```
a=input();k=list(a)
for i in a:k.remove(i);k.insert(ord(i)-97,i)
print"".join(k)[::-1]
```

---

## Python 3, 88 bytes

```
a=input();k=list(a)
for i in a:k.remove(i);k.insert(ord(i)-97,i)
print("".join(k)[::-1])
```

---

#### Examples

Python 2:

```
$ python2 test.py
"flower"
rweolf
```

Python 3:

```
$ python3 test.py
flower
rweolf
```

Comment: `k.remove` removes the first instance, so this is going to fail for something like `baa`.

Answer (score 2):

### Javascript ES6, <s>136</s> <s>134</s> 131 bytes

```
s=>([...s].map(c=>{s=s.replace(c,'');p=s.length+97-c.charCodeAt();s=s.substr(0,p)+c.toUpperCase()+s.substring(p)}),s.toLowerCase())
```

Note that I take great care not to move the same character twice, otherwise `pizza` turns into `zipza` when it should be `zzipa`. There's also an edge case dealing with not removing characters prematurely; `characters` becomes maybe `srtrchaeac` or `srtrheccaa` if you do it wrongly but it should be `srtrhcecaa`. Another tricky word is `abracadabra` for which the output `rrabaaadcba` would be incorrect; `rrbcdaaabaa` would be correct.

Edit: Shaved off two bytes by using substring which automatically coerces its arguments to the range 0..length.

Edit: Shaved off three bytes by changing the first substring to substr as suggested by user81665.

Comment: I think you could use `substr` instead of `substring`.

Comment: `slice` is better (I think).

Comment: @ՊՓԼՃՐՊՃՈԲՍԼ He can't because passing negative numbers into `slice` breaks it.

Comment: oh forgot about that.

Comment: Yeah, there was a little mistake with the `pizza` test case you put on my post, but I fixed it.

Comment: Ugh, and I thought I'd checked against my answer too. Very sorry about that, and also the other typos that crept in (my fault for doing it so late at night.)

Answer (score 2):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang) (v2), 58 bytes

```
;=i~!=sP;W<=i+1iLs=sI>0=l-L=tSs iT@-A=cGs iT95+c tSt lFcOs
```

[Try it online!](https://knight-lang.netlify.app/#WyI7PWl+IT1zUDtXPD1pKzFpTHM9c0k+MD1sLUw9dFNzIGlUQC1BPWNHcyBpVDk1K2MgdFN0IGxGY09zIiwiZmxvd2VyIiwiMi4wIl0=)

expanded:

```
; = idx ~1 # ie -1
; = str PROMPT
; WHILE < (= idx + idx 1) (LENGTH str)
    ; = chr GET str idx 1 # ie get the char at index `idx`
    ; = tmp SET str idx 1 "" # delete that chr
    ; = index - (LENGTH str) (- (ASCII chr) 95)
    : = str
        IF (> 0 index)
            : + chr tmp
        # ELSE:
            : SET tmp index 0 chr # insert the char there
: OUTPUT str
```

Comment: How do you run this?  When I click the triangle [here](https://knight-lang.netlify.app/#WyI7PWl+IT1zUDtXPD1pKzFpTHM9c0k+MD1sLUw9dFNzIGlUQC1BPWNHcyBpVDk1K2MgdFN0IGxGYyIsImNoYXJhY3RlcnMiLCIyLjAiXQ==) I get an "Error: Missing argument 2 for func ';'"...

Comment: D'oh! I forgot to copy the `Os` at the end. updating now

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, <s>18</s> 17 bytes

```
uXeS,Z-lzhx;HGHzk
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=uXeS%2CZ-lzhx%3BHGHzk&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=giraffe%0Aflower%0Apineapple%0Abaa&debug=1).

Iterates using reduce over the input string, inserting into a string, base case empty string, at the correct position.

Answer (score 1):

## , 23 chars / 40 bytes

```
ᴉⓜΞăМƲ ïꝈ-ᶛą$,0),0,$;Ξ⨝
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter2.html?eval=false&input=flower&code=%E1%B4%89%E2%93%9C%CE%9E%C4%83%D0%9C%C6%B2%20%C3%AF%EA%9D%88-%E1%B6%9B%C4%85%24%2C0%29%2C0%2C%24%3B%CE%9E%E2%A8%9D)</kbd>

## Explanation

```
ᴉⓜΞăМƲ ïꝈ-ᶛą$,0),0,$;Ξ⨝ // implicit: ï=input, ᴉ=input split into chars, Ξ=empty array, ᶛ=lowercase alphabet
ᴉⓜ                      // map over input chars
   ΞăМƲ ïꝈ-ᶛą$,0),0,$;   // use splice to insert map item into Ξ at requested index
                      Ξ⨝ // join Ξ
                         // implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 56 bytes

Port of [Morgan Thrapp's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68830/11261).

```ruby
->x{y=[]
x.chars{y[[x.size-_1.ord+96,0].max,0]=_1}
y*""}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsEiN9ulpSVpuhY3LXTtKqorbaNjuSr0kjMSi4qrK6OjK_SKM6tSdeMN9fKLUrQtzXQMYvVyEyuAlG28YS1XpZaSUi1Uv1FBaUmxglu0UnpmUWJaWqpSLBdMJC0nvzy1CEmgILOqKlEpFqJzwQIIDQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 25 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
.āDvyUΣNsXQiIgAXнk2t+-]€н
```

Outputs as a list of characters.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f70ijS1ll6LnFfsURgZme6Y4RF/ZmG5Vo68Y@alpzYe///@mZRYlpaakA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfaVLmNJ/vSONLmWVoecW@xVHBGZGpjtGXNibbVSirRv7qGnNhb3/lfTCXOy9lBQ0Du/XVNL5H62UnlmUmJaWqqSjlJaTX55aBGQUZOalJhYU5KSC2VVViUA6MakoMTkxBUQBeckZiUBuSWpRsVIsAA).

**Explanation:**

Unfortunately 05AB1E lacks a builtin to insert a character at a certain index without removing the current character at that index. So instead I'm using a sort-by, where I only modify the index of the current character.

```python
.ā                  # Enumerate the (implicit) input-string, pairing each character with
                    # its (0-based) index (to make them all unique)
  D                 # Duplicate it
   v                # Loop over each pair `y` in this list:
    yU              #  Put pair `y` in variable `X`
    Σ               #  Sort the list of pairs by:
     N              #   Push the current sort-index
     s              #   Swap so the current pair is at the top of the stack
      XQi           #   If it's equal to pair `X`:
         Ig         #    Push the input-length
           A        #    Push the lowercase alphabet
            Xн      #    Push the character of pair `X`
              k     #    Get the (0-based) index of this character in the alphabet
               2t+  #    Add sqrt(2) to it (+1 to make it 1-based, and +0.414 so it'll
                    #    come before the actual integer-index)
                  - #    Subtract this index from the input-length
   ]                # Close both the sort-by and loop
    €               # Map over each pair
     н              #  And only leave its character
                    # (after which the list of characters is output implicitly)
```